# SetOnClickListener Mono for Android

Tags: android

I'm following a sample code on how to create Login and Register process using Mono For Android. The sample was develop in java and I'm stuck on how to implement the setOnClickListener in Mono For Android.

Please find the below code.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // setting default screen to login.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        TextView registerScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_register);

        // Listening to register new account link
        registerScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Switching to Register screen
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Can somebody guide me on how to do it.

--edit

```
public class LoginActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.LoginLayout);
        TextView registerScreen = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.link_to_register);
        registerScreen.Click += (sender, e) => 
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, typeof(RegisterActivity));
            this.StartActivity(i);
        };
    }
}
```

Thanks and regards,
klaydze

Comment: Hi, if you look at the code when you click the TextView assuming it's a hyperlink it will open the registration form. Now i'm having hard time to implement that using Mono For Android because it was written in java. You can check the full tutorial here. http://www.androidhive.info/2011/10/android-login-and-registration-screen-design/

Answer (score 0):

Do you add this in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

```
<activity
    android:name=".RegisterActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.REGISTERACTIVITY" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: It's very stupid to answer my own question but it's now working. Please see my original post.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write below Code before setonclicklistener, it will solve your problem.

```
registerScreen.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#007FFF'><u>Click to Open Next Activity</u></font>"));
registerScreen.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for shorter code

```
TextView tV = (TextView)app.FindViewById(Resource.Id.mytextview);
tV.Click += (s, e) => 
{ 
   StartActivity(typeof(RegisterActivity));

   //this is what you currently have
   //var registerActivity = new Intent (this, typeof(RegisterActivity));
   //StartActivity(registerActivity);  
};
```